# 2 MySQL Queries can't be combined?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, multiple-columns

I got the following 2 mysql_queries:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tenderID='".$_REQUEST["tenderID"]."'");
while($tender = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $zippy = $tender["ziparea"];
    $zipResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ziparea = '".$zippy."'");
    while($zip = mysql_fetch_array($zipResult)) {
        ....
    }
}
```

The first query works like I want it to work.

table1 has the column 'ziparea', but it has **always** just 1 entry for each ziparea (01 to 99).
table2 also has the column 'ziparea', but it **sometimes** has more than 1 entry for each ziparea (for example: there is 5 entries for ziparea '24'; means 5 rows)

I need all information from both tables, I tried to merge both queries with "JOIN", but I couldn't solve the problem, which also exists in the code on the top.

The problem is, that - even though there is only 1 entry in table1 - it always gives as much rows, as table2 will put out for query 2.

Means if the ziparea is 24 and in table1 is only 1 row with ziparea '24' (and of course only 1 row with the matching tenderID), but table2 has 5 rows for the ziparea '24', there will be 5 times the same value from query one.

I can't really figure out why.

Maybe you have the solution for me.

*Structure of table1 and table2:*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAXF6.png

Comment: why not do a join between tables?

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) alert!

Comment: if I join them, I have the same problem, because of the multiple entries in table 2 for the column 'ziparea'. .... If I then use `<?php echo utf8_encode($tender["tenderName"]); ?>` it will give me 5 times the same tenderName, even though there is only one tenderName... it seems to fill up for the rows in table2... this duplicates my html contents (5x)

Answer (score 0):

you are wrong. A join query 
    SELECT * 
    FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 on t1.ziparea = t2.ziparea 
    WHERE tenderID='".$_REQUEST["tenderID"]."'"

between table1 and table2 must show you

```
tender tendername clientinfo tenderstart created byuser ziparea id ziparea customerid ... 
1 test thisisatest 12.12.1234 31.03.14 02:52 roy 24 50 10400 ...
1 test thisisatest 12.12.1234 31.03.14 02:52 roy 24 51 13723 ...
1 test thisisatest 12.12.1234 31.03.14 02:52 roy 24 52 23720 ...
1 test thisisatest 12.12.1234 31.03.14 02:52 roy 24 53 11237 ...
1 test thisisatest 12.12.1234 31.03.14 02:52 roy 24 54 24216 ...
```

the you can use php to show the result like you want.

**edit** 
to print like you want, you can do something like this:

```
$tenderid = -1;
while($tender = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($tenderid != $tender["tenderid"]){
       $tenderid = $tender["tenderid"]
       echo $tender["tenderid"]. " ". $tender["tendername"] ... $tender["ziparea"];
     }
   echo $tender["id"]. " " . $tender["customerid"] ... "<br />";
```

}

Comment: yes, but if I want to output `<?php echo utf8_encode($tender["tenderName"]); ?>` I will get 5 times "this is a test", which means my web content will duplicate... that's the problem .... I already tried "LIMIT 1" for the first query, but even with LIMIT 1 I get 5 outputs

Comment: not is a problem. Is the "normal" case because the join. You cannot simply do a echo. You must to iterate your result an format the result like you need to show it

Comment: how could I iterate the result that there will be only 1 output for all the information of table1?

Comment: but with "while" it'll output 5 times "test" when I output $tender["tender Name"], no?

Comment: no. it print it just one time. because print  $tender["tender Name"] only whed tenderid changes. In your case, you have just one tenderid and then printit just one time

Answer (score 0):

There's a one-to-one-or-more relationship between the tables. If you `JOIN` them you'll get the columns from table1 repeated for each table2 row. That's just how it works.

If what you're trying to do is replicate the output from your screenshot in HTML (or in Excel by lying to it about the file type), you can do your table1 query, print the table1 columns, then loop on your table2 query, printing blank columns for each row after the first. Something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tenderID='".$_REQUEST["tenderID"]."'");

print '<table>';
while($tender = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print '<tr>';
    # Print your table1 columns
    print '<td>'.$tender['tenderID'].'</td>';
    ⋮
    print '<td>'.$tender['byUser'].'</td>';

    # Now loop on table2. The counter variable is to keep it neat.
    $zip_counter = 0;
    $zippy = $tender["ziparea"];
    $zipResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ziparea = '".$zippy."'");
    while($zip = mysql_fetch_array($zipResult)) {
        if ($zip_counter > 0) {
            # On table2 rows after the first, start the table row,
            # then print a blank column for each table1 column
            print '<tr>'
            print '<td/>';
            ⋮
            print '<td/>';
        }

        # Print the table2 columns
        print '<td'>.$zip['ziparea'].'</td>';
        ⋮
        print '<td'>.$zip['mail'].'</td>';
        print '</tr>';

        $zip_counter++;
    }
}
print '</table>';
```

The other option is to do it all in one query, then ignore the repeated table1 values after the first. This is probably preferable because it saves the setup and tear-down for the table2 query.

```
$this_tender_id = $_REQUEST['tenderID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT t1.tenderID,
                              ⋮
                              t1.byUser,
                              t2.ziparea,
                              ⋮
                              t2.mail
                         FROM table1 t1
                         JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.ziparea = t1.ziparea
                        WHERE t1.tenderID = {$this_tender_id}
                      "
);

$row_counter = 0;

print '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print '<tr>';
    # For the first row, print the table1 columns,
    # otherwise print blank columns. 
    if ($row_counter == 0) {
        print '<td>'.$row['tenderID'].'</td>';
        ⋮
        print '<td>'.$row['byUser'].'</td>';
    }
    else {
        print '<td/>';
        ⋮
        print '<td/>';
    }

    # Print the table2 columns
    print '<td'>.$row['ziparea'].'</td>';
    ⋮
    print '<td'>.$row['mail'].'</td>';
    print '</tr>';

    $row_counter++;
}
print '</table>';
```

Comment: thanks for you answer... I'm sorry for the picture, but now you misunderstood... I never wanted to replicate the screenshot with my php output, the screenshot should just show the table structure..... my output is on this php-page and the problem is, that the data from table1 is repeater.. .when I output it with a while statement, I get 5x the web content... http://i.stack.imgur.com/ezCJK.jpg

Comment: Ah, I see now. Still the same principle can apply. Suppress the redundant _Das ist ein test_ sections and repeat the desired sections created from the table2 query.

Also, @mark-baker is quite correct. You really should be sanitizing your inputs. See [PHP: Sanitize filters - Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).